Make a grayscale tif into a 4-band RGBA tif using gdal
I have a grayscale raster which returns the following information when I run gdalinfo on it
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  626025.040,  234200.730) (  1d17'24.75"E, 51d57'35.41"N)
Lower Left  (  626025.040,  231749.730) (  1d17'18.94"E, 51d56'16.20"N)
Upper Right (  628094.540,  234200.730) (  1d19'13.00"E, 51d57'32.37"N)
Lower Right (  628094.540,  231749.730) (  1d19' 7.15"E, 51d56'13.16"N)
Center      (  627059.790,  232975.230) (  1d18'15.96"E, 51d56'54.29"N)
Band 1 Block=4139x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0

I am looking to use gdal commandline to make it a 4-band RGBA tiff
I've tried gdal_translate -ot Byte -of GTiff -b 1 -b 1 -b 1 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB "input.tif" "output.tif" but then the tif doesnt even appear on the map

You must consider two things:

The source is Float32 and target has 8 bit. It makes sense to scale the min/max of the source data to use the 0-255 range in the output. That will fix the "nothing seen on the map" issue. Gdal_translate can do that.

Using -b three times with gdal_translate creates a 3-band image. You want alpha, but gdal_translate cannot create it for you. Use gdalwarp instead.


Note: The -b/-srcband option in gdalwarp was introduced in GDAL version 3.7.
Because gdalwarp does not support scaling, two commands are needed:
gdal_translate -ot byte -scale single_band_32.tif single_band_byte.tif

gdalwarp -b 1 -b 1 -b 1 -dstalpha single_band_byte.tif 8bitRGBA.tif

gdalinfo 8bitRGBA.tif

Band 1 Block=3000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=3000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=3000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=3000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha

If you want to edit the colorinterpretations of the bands, polish the metadata with gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html#cmdoption-colorinterp_-X

-colorinterp_ {red|green|blue|alpha|gray|undefined}
Change the color interpretation of band X (where X is a valid band
number, starting at 1).


gdalwarp does not support the -b flag ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-b'

Do you have on old GDAL (<3.7)? See https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-b and the example in -srcband that is a synonym.

Apologies, yes I was on the wrong osgeo4w shell. All 3 rgb bands are coming out as the same min/max

Do you expect something else?
